# How to reference field by index on SQL?

Tags: sql

In this SQL query:

```
select
name,
age,
(select sum(something) from sometable where sometable.code = people.code)
from people
where THIRD_COLUMN > 0
```

How to reference the result of the third column without having to repeat the SQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  You *can* use a subquery and give the column a name, though:

```
select p.name, p.age, p.THIRD_COLUMN
from (select name, age,
             (select sum(something) from sometable where sometable.code = people.code
             ) as THIRD_COLUMN
      from people
     ) p
where THIRD_COLUMN > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know which dms you use but in mysql you can use:

```
select
name,
age,
(select sum(something) from sometable where sometable.code = people.code) sum_people
from people
having sum_people > 0
```

Comment: Having without group?

Comment: You're right! ;-) The correct statement can build like this:

select
id,
name,
age,
(select sum(something) from sometable where sometable.code = people.code) sum_people
from people
group by id
having sum_people > 0

Thx for your hint. ;-)